# Most efficient way to format a string in scala with leading Zero's and a comma instead of a decimal point

Tags: scala, string-formatting, dataformat

Trying to create a simple function whereby a String value is passed in i.e. "1" and the formatter should return the value with leading zeros and 5 decimal points however instead of a dot '.' I'm trying to return it with a comma ','

This is what I have attempted however its not working because the decimalFormatter can only handle numbers and not a string. The end goal is to get from "1" to "000000001,00000" - character length is 14 in total. 5 0's after the comma and the remaining before the comma should be padded out 0's to fill the 9 digit requirement.

Another example would be going from "913" to "000000913,00000"

```
 def numberFormatter (value: String): String =
{
     import java.text.DecimalFormat
     val decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("%09d,00000")
     val formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(value)
     return formattedValue
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to format a `String` padded with spaces, but with zeros not so much. Still, it's not so hard to roll your own.

```
def numberFormatter(value :String) :String =
  ("0" * (9 - value.length)) + value + ",00000"

numberFormatter("1")    //res0: String = 000000001,00000
numberFormatter("913")  //res1: String = 000000913,00000
```

Note that this won't truncate the input `String`. So if `value` is longer than 9 characters then the result will be longer than the desired 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

def f(value:String) = new java.text.DecimalFormat("000000000.00000").format(value.toFloat).replace(".", ",")

scala> f(913f)
res5: String = 000000913,00000

// Edit: Use .toFloat (or .toInt, .toLong, etc.) to convert your string to a number first.

Comment: This does not address the issue of having a string as input.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  But it would be trivial to add .toFloat

Comment: Edited; this is how you might do it if your input is a number but the data type is string.  But the other answer is fine if your input is really an arbitrary string and not a number.